# Animate two layers along identical path

Tags: after-effects, animation

I have made simple animation where a hand drags an item onto a page.  I wanted them to take a curved path so I have added a bezier curve to the path as shown below

[image]

This only effects one of the layers so I manually put the same curve into the second layer but it is not perfect.  I can see the hand and the contact us box move slightly differently.

How do I lock both layers on the exact same path?

Answer (score 1):

You could Parent one layer to the other.

This means that one layer controls the position/rotation/scale of the other layer.

See https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/layer-properties.html#parent_and_child_layers
for more info.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @inevitably answer. You shall use parenting, but better not to parent one layer to another, but create Null Object with that monition curve, and parent both layers to it.

**Why it may be important:**

If you need any motion of "parent layer" in variant provided by @inevitably, it will be pretty difficult to move it without moving child layer. But with Null Object, it will be pretty easy.